# Get string between two complicated string in a string C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, split, substring

**I have shared the relevant image below.**

[image]

Text in image ;

"C:\Users\Hp\OneDrive-blablablabla\Masaustu\EdaGorsel\**4.PNG**\tmanager\tmanager\t2022/12/12\r\nddd\tV1.0"

1. I only want **4.PNG** from the above post

2.I should not use special names or filenames

3.Ex: \t between \ like this

***I hope I was able to explain my problem***

Comment: So, does the string always contains a dot, with an extension afterward? Is there a valid range for the extension length?

Comment: Unfortunately your problem is unclear. What is the criteria here? Is the string you are looking for always in EdaGorsel directory?

Comment: Can you show more examples of texts and values you want to get? Can you explain *how* code should know that "4.PNG" is the correct target? Is it always of the form "*.PNG", is it the last path fragment before a \t (=a TAB character), something else?

Comment: Looks like TAB-separated data. You could split on '\t', take the first element and then extract the file name using `Path.GetFileName(...)`.

Comment: the directory will always change @DenisSchaf

Comment: I don't want to split the index too much. I just want to get the image. @KlausGütter

Answer (score 3):

you could use a Regex match to get this part of the url :

```
private Regex _regex = new Regex(@"^.*\\(?<Image>.*\.PNG)\\.*$");
```

(You can test regex [here](https://regex101.com/))

Then use this to read the match :

```
var result = _regex.Match(url).Groups["Image"].Value;
```

Another, simplier solution, would be to use :

```
url.Split("\\")[6];
```

This works only if the searched part is always at the same spot.

Comment: Thank u for all.Your answer enough for me.I'm still working on.I hope fix it

Answer (score 2):

You can split your strings into many shorter ones using .Split function:

```
string[] words = path.Split("\\");
```

Using the double \ to escape the character..

If you don't guarantee that the string you need is always at the same position, you can use this to fetch it from the list:

```
string neededString = words .FirstOrDefault(str => str.Contains(".PNG"));
```

This will return the first instance of any word from your string that contains ".png" in it.

Answer (score 1):

there is sevral ways

1. if you know number of "" in your string then split it(str.Split(' \ ')) and get wanted index
2. use regular expersion to extract filename